# Not sure if i should be doing a type III anova

Tags: r, statistical-significance, anova

I was initially using the following anova formula in R
aov.out <- aov(column_name ~ core * ethnicity, data=mydata)

However i noticed that my dataset is quite unbalanced :
[image]

In light of that I tried looking at ways to do unbalanced anova tests but haven't had much luck understanding what I should be doing. I think I should be doing a type III anova test? but I'm not too sure

Any help appreciated

Answer (score 0):

As I understand it, unbalanced data alone are not a sufficient justification for performing a Type III ANOVA. Rather, the three different sum of squares (SS) types will yield different outcomes depending on if the data are balanced or not.

You should consider the research question when deciding on the appropriate SS treatment. For instance, if your independent variables (IV) are ordered and you want to calculate the SS for IV2 *given* IV1, then a Type 1 SS may be most appropriate.  If you don’t care about the sequence of IVs, or an interaction effect, Type 2 SS may be more appropriate. Type 3 if you wish to consider an interaction effect in a non-sequential manner.

Of course, there is more nuance associated with choosing the SS treatment, and you may find the following resources helpful:

For a simple read: https://towardsdatascience.com/anovas-three-types-of-estimating-sums-of-squares-don-t-make-the-wrong-choice-91107c77a27a

For a comprehensive read, and perhaps more relevant to your particular situation: Langsrud Ø. ANOVA for unbalanced data: Use Type II instead of Type III sums of squares. Statistics and Computing. 2003 Apr;13(2):163-7.
https://link.springer.com/content/pdf/10.1023/A:1023260610025.pdf